# Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)

Tags: ruby, curl, net-http

I'm trying to convert my WORKING curl code into ruby using net/http.
I'm getting a  Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET) error and I'm not sure why.
Here is the working curl:

```
   curl -X POST -u "apikey:MYAPIKEY" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"url":"https://www.cnn.com/2020/08/20/politics/trump-ballot-florida-lawsuit/index.html","features": {"sentiment": {}, "categories": {},"concepts": {},"entities": {},"keywords": {} } }' "https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2018-03-19"
```

RUBY

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2018-03-19')

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.basic_auth("apikey", "MYAPIKEY")
request.set_form_data({
                  "url" => "https://www.cnn.com/2020/08/20/politics/trump-ballot-florida-lawsuit/index.html",
                  "features"    => "{'sentiment': {}, 'categories': {},'concepts': {},'entities': {},'keywords': {} } }"
                  })

request.add_field("Content-Type", "application/json")

response = http.request(request)
puts response.inspect
```

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you need a zero-dependency solution, it's worth looking at things like [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) for doing HTTP in Ruby.

Comment: If that's supposed to be JSON, which you seem to indicate with the headers, it should be valid JSON. Check with a linting tool, as `'` is not a valid JSON quote. Tip: Don't write JSON by hand, use `JSON.dump` on a Hash (`require 'json'`)

Comment: Thank you @tadman.  I didn't know about Faraday.  This site was a big help working with Faraday: http://zetcode.com/web/rubyfaraday/

Comment: It's pretty popular so it's not hard to find examples. Hope that makes it a lot easier to do what you were trying here.